# Deploying Play 2.0 app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, bind, playframework-2.0

So I am kind of new to setting up servers. And I have been struggling with various sql issues all night. I think the only thing that sits between me and a successfully running play app is this: error

```
Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=80 `
2012-04-04T05:58:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 1
2012-04-04T05:58:53+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_cd914b667dae168
2012-04-04T05:58:56+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - Application started (Prod)
2012-04-04T05:58:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops, cannot start the server.
2012-04-04T05:58:56+00:00 app[web.1]: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:80
... more errors
```

Does anyone spot any problems? Do I need any java options arguments?

I tried specifying a user port in the `Procfile`, and got a different error message:

```
2012-04-04T07:01:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhttp.port=2000`
2012-04-04T07:01:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 1
2012-04-04T07:01:40+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_cd914b667dae168
2012-04-04T07:01:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - Application started (Prod)
2012-04-04T07:01:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 2000...
2012-04-04T07:01:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 2000, should be 47248 (see environment variable PORT)
2012-04-04T07:01:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2012-04-04T07:01:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-04-04T07:01:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have no idea what is happening. How do I change this environment variable? This heroku process model is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not allowing Heroku to specify the port.  Googling your error I find: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r11__bad_bind

So instead of doing this:

> web: target/start -Dhttp.port=80

Do this

> web: target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT

James has a nice writeup on getting a more advanced Play 2.0 app deployed [here](http://www.jamesward.com/2012/02/21/play-framework-2-with-scala-anorm-json-coffeescript-jquery-heroku).